# window.frames[1].document.getElementById Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a js problem or I don't know I can't see the problem.

When I check the value of

```
window.frames[1].document.getElementById('GroupPolicyIdentity.policyStartDate').value;
```

from console, I see the value, but in the js code I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined.
```

I am trying to do this.

```
var policyStartDate = 
window.frames[1].document.getElementById('GroupPolicyIdentity.policyStartDate').value;
```

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes I' am sure, it is an old project and it has 2 frames in the page.
I already see the data coming.

Comment: can you check `window.frames.length`?

Comment: @devgirl Can you tell me how are you checking with JS...Inside the script tag??

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to try like this, after all the frames are loaded...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
    var policyStartDate = window.frames[1].document.getElementById('GroupPolicyIdentity.policyStartDate').value;
    alert(policyStartDate);
}
</script>
```

This worked for me...Although with different frame samples. The reason why you were getting following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

is because of frames were not loaded. If you would have checked there itself, for `window.frames.length`, it resulted as `0`

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by document.getElementById('GroupPolicyIdentity.policyStartDate').value. I don't know how it worked bu the answer is that.
Thanks for everybody